# NSOutputStream blocking, HasBytesAvailable event was not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, external-accessory, nsinputstream, nsoutputstream

I am trying to create custom framework that will deal with `ExternalAccessory.framework` to do read/write operation with the connected accessory.

I can able to create a session and open the device to do read/write operations. 
Problem i am facing was, when i try to write data using `NSOutputStream.write` from the application, data successfully received by the accessory but after that UI was not responding and data returned byte accessory was not received by the app(HasBytesAvailable was not called)

Here my `UIViewController.swift`

```
let sessionHandler = SessionHandler().sharedController()
```

in `ViewDidLoad()`

```
let runLoop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
sessionHandler.openDeviceWithProtocolString(runLoop)
```

`@IBAction` calling `sessionHandler._WriteData()`

This `SessionHandler` class was in inside my custom SDK (custom framework)

Here my `SessionHandler` Class

```
import UIKit
import ExternalAccessory


public class SessionHandler: NSObject, NSStreamDelegate {

    var readData: NSMutableData?
    var writeData: NSMutableData?
    var _session: EASession?

    public func sharedController() -> SessionHandler{
        var sessionController: SessionHandler?
        if sessionController == nil {
            sessionController = SessionHandler()
        }
        return sessionController!
    }

    func getConnectedAccessoris() -> Array<EAAccessory>{
        let accessories : Array<EAAccessory> = EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager().connectedAccessories
        return accessories
    }


    public func openDeviceWithProtocolString(_runLoop: NSRunLoop){
        print("Inside openDeviceWithProtocolString")
        let _accessories = getConnectedAccessoris()
        var _accessory: EAAccessory?
        for acsy in _accessories {
            if acsy.protocolStrings.contains("my.protocol.string") {
                _accessory = acsy
            }
        }
        if _accessory != nil {
            _session = EASession(accessory: _accessory!, forProtocol: "my.protocol.string")
            print("EASession create :: \(_session)")
            if _session != nil {

                _session?.inputStream?.delegate = self
                _session?.inputStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(_runLoop, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
                _session?.inputStream?.open()
                print("Input stream Opened")
                _session?.outputStream?.delegate = self
                _session?.outputStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(_runLoop, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
                _session?.outputStream?.open()
                print("Output Stream Opened")
            }else {
                print("SessionHandler : session nil")
            }
        }
    }



    public func _readData() {
        print("Trying to read data")
        let INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE = 65536
        let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE)
        while ((_session?.inputStream?.hasBytesAvailable) != nil) {
            let bytesRead = _session?.inputStream?.read(buf, maxLength: INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE)
            if readData == nil {
                readData = NSMutableData()
            }
            readData?.appendBytes(buf, length: bytesRead!)
        }
        if readData != nil {
            let data: NSData = readData!
            let count = data.length / sizeof(UInt8)

            // create an array of Uint8
            var array = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)

            // copy bytes into array
            data.getBytes(&array, length:count * sizeof(UInt8))
            print("Data Received :: \(array)")
            validateData(array)
        }
    }

    public func _writeData() {

        while _session?.outputStream?.hasSpaceAvailable != nil && writeData?.length > 0 {
            print("Writting bytes :: \(writeData?.bytes)")
            let bytesWritten = _session?.outputStream?.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>((writeData?.bytes)!), maxLength: (writeData?.length)!)
            print("written bytes : \(bytesWritten)")
            if bytesWritten == -1 {
                //Write error
                print("written error")
                break
            }else if bytesWritten > 0 {
                print("Written success")
                validateData(writeData)
                writeData?.replaceBytesInRange(NSMakeRange(0, bytesWritten!), withBytes: nil, length: 0)
            }
        }
    }


    func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
        switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEvent.None:
            print("NSStream None")
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
            print("Open Completed")
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
            print("Has Bytes Available")
            _readData()
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
            print("Hase space Available")
            _writeData()
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
            print("Error occurred")
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
            print("End Encountered")
            break
        default:
            print("No stream event")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

```
sessionHandler.openDeviceWithProtocolString(runLoop)
```

Isn't it supposed to be called on another thread?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is too late, but

```
while ((_session?.inputStream?.hasBytesAvailable) != nil)
```

looks like an infinite loop to me, because true/false will always be != nil.